# Job/Transformation scheduling in Pentaho

Tags: database, repository, scheduler, pentaho-data-integration

I have Pentaho-Spoon on my Windows machine and all the transformations/jobs are stored in a Database Repository.

Now, we want to set up a scheduler for the transformations and jobs.

Being a newbie, I just know that I need to use a batch file in Windows Scheduler with the address of kitchen.bat/pan.bat and address of the job/transformation to be scheduled.

Do I need to install the Pentaho Data Integration tool on the server as well on which the repository is located? And even if I do so how to get the address from the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the help of Windows Scheduler.Just need to trigger a batch file similar to the shown in the example below:

```
C:\\data-integration\kitchen.bat /rep:"PentahoRepository" /job:"TestJob" /dir:\<direcoryname> /user:<usernamm> /pass:<password> /level:Basic
```